# Unreadable characters on output window

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I got an error on Output windows while compiling, I got some characters that I can't eliminate.

`In file included from [01m[K/home/pablo/workspace/`
`[01;35m[Kwarning: [m[Ktype qualifiers ignored`
As you can see there is some trash caracters that I cannot read, and my Output/Window doesn't process.

I've changed Terminal Font (Settings > Features > Terminal > Font Family)
And also text editor Font (Settings > Text Editor > Font > Font Family)
And set them both to 'monospace'

But, I still getting those characters.

Comment: these are ANSI Escape sequences, your terminal does not support them, Set your compiler to disable color output or use a different terminal

Comment: A peer is using the same config than me, and It works good.

Comment: because you see something different your setups are NOT the same.

Comment: They actaully where diferent, but we didn't see it. You were right, I've disabled color output.